# i have to replace all the ? with X in unix except some valid?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

It kind of some complicated question. I want to replace all the ? in the file with X. But the problem is there are some valid ? also there in input file.

eg:

input:

```
HELLO ?, WELCOME TO THE NEW WORLD??23, and you are most ? valid person.
```

output:

```
HELLO X, WELCOME TO THE NEW WORLDX?23, and you are most X valid person.
```

here, ? comes before 23 is valid one.. like ?23, many values are there. ?24,?33,?45, etc.,

I tried with sed script, but able to find the exact command.

Script which i used:

```
LINE_NUM=0 

while IFS= read -r LINE    
do  
LINE_NUM=$?   
EXTRACTED=`echo "${LINE}" |grep '?23' |  sed 's|^.*\?23||; s|\?[0-9].*$||'`

if [ -n "$EXTRACTED" ]    
then    
UPDATED=`echo "$EXTRACTED" | sed 's/?/X/g'`    
UPDATED_1=`echo "$UPDATED" | awk '{gsub("/","%",$0); print}'`    
if [ $EXTRACTED != $UPDATED ]   
then    
LATEST_VALUE=`echo  "${LINE}" | sed "s|${EXTRACTED}|${UPDATED}|g"`    
fi

LATEST_VALUE=`echo  "${LINE}"`    
echo "$LATEST_VALUE"  >> outputfile.txt   
else    
echo "$LINE" >> outputfile.txt    
fi   
done<inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 posted the script which i developed

Comment: Please copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix all of the issues it will tell you about. Also read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for the reasons not to write a shell read loop to do this at all.

Comment: You need to be able to define in English which ones are valid vs. which ones are not valid.  Then you can write code to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ echo "HELLO ?, WELCOME TO THE NEW WORLD??23, and you are most ? valid person." | 
  sed -E 's/\?([^0-9]|$)/X\1/g'


HELLO X, WELCOME TO THE NEW WORLDX?23, and you are most X valid person.
```

here it escapes `?` followed by a digit (or end of line).  If your list is more restricted change the regex there.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. In GNU `awk` please try following. Simple explanation would be, setting record separator as 1 ? followed by 1 digit, using global substitution to substitute `?` with `X` in current records; setting correct output record separator as RT, then print current line.

```
awk -v RS='[?][0-9]' '{gsub(/\?/,"X");ORS=RT} 1' Input_file
```